# Is this question correct in grammar and does it even make sense specially whats between " "

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, grammaticality

Is this question correct in grammar and does it even make sense specially whats between " "

How did the world coped/dealt with oil spills "at the time that events occurs and in the long run"

Thanks